# Cannot create a reference to an object with a NULL id. with mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

im having the Cannot create a reference to an object with a NULL id error, i dont know whats the problem, i dont know if i did everything right or not.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/insert", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createPath(@RequestBody Path path) {
        log.info("Insert of the path");



        pathService.insertPath(path);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(path);
    }
```

thats the code of point path, and its just a normal controller just to try the insert, same is for pointPath controller, i dont have any controls at all

```
Point path :

@Data
@Document(collection = "pointPath")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class PointPath {

    @Id
    private String id;
    
    private String streetName;
    
    private String numberStreet;

    private String municipality;
    
    private Integer zipCode;
    
    private Double latitude;
    
    private Double longitude;
    
}
```

Path :

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "path")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Path {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private PointPath starterPoint;

    private PointPath endPoint;

    @DBRef
    private List<PointPath> intermediatePoints = new ArrayList<>();

    private boolean circuit;

    // counting minuts
    private Integer time;

    // counting meters
    private Integer totalDistance;

}
```

I can easily create a pointPath document

but if i try to do a path insert

```
{   
   
    "starterPoint": {
        "streetName": "Via Roma",
        "numberStreet": "12",
        "municipality": "Roma",
        "zipCode": 22100,
        "latitude": 41.902782,
        "longitude": 12.496366
    },
    "endPoint": {
        "streetName": "Piazza del Popolo",
        "numberStreet": "",
        "municipality": "Roma",
        "zipCode": 22187,
        "latitude": 41.910732,
        "longitude": 12.476200
    },
    "intermediatePoints": [
        {
            "$ref": "pointPath",
            "$id": "640a263e585b0232fee17908"
        }
    ],
    "circuit": false,
    "time": 30,
    "totalDistance": 6000
}
```

like this, it shows the 500 error
what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to give a id to path.like `path.setId(sequence.nextId());`